# Determine capacity of tape drive

Tags: tape

Is there a way via `mtx` or `mt`, or else via some value stored in `/sys` or `/proc`, to know the capacity of a tape in a tape drive (such as a LTO7 cassette in a DELL TL4000)?

I have attempted [mt](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mt) with the operations `tell` and `status`.

> `status`
>
>   Print status information about the tape unit. 
>   (If the density code is "no translation" in the status output,
>   this does not affect working of the tape drive.)
>
> `tell`
>
>   (SCSI tapes) Tell the current block on tape. 
>   This operation is available on some Tandberg and Wangtek streamers
>   and some SCSI-2 tape drives.

but even being uid=0 (root) it reports
`/dev/sg2: operation not permitted`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `mt` command, you need to use
`/dev/stN` instead of `/dev/sgN`
because `mt` uses tape driver. 
For example, load the cartridge into the drive and try this way:

```
$ mt -f /dev/st0 status
```

NOTE that `/dev/st0` depends on your environment.